# Azure function python: blob.set method store empty file in blob container through output binding

Tags: python, azure, csv, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

An azure function is triggered via blob trigger event.

- Trigger gives a csv file as `myblob` to the function from
  `new-container`.
- The function also gets `base.csv` as `base` from `base-container`.
- Both CSV files are read via pandas library.
- Some processing is done to create `df_final`.
- `df_final` is converted to string representation through `to_csv()`.
- The string representation of CSV is converted to utf-8 encoding.
- The `blobout.set()` store encoded CSV to `base-container` as `base.csv`.

Everything works as expected but the only problem is when `base.csv` is stored via `blobout.set`. It's an empty bile with 0 bytes size. Even though df_final is having records.

****init**.py**

```
import logging
import pandas as pd

import azure.functions as func
from io import BytesIO


def main(myblob: func.InputStream, base: func.InputStream, blobout: func.Out[bytes]):
    df_base = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(base.read()))
    df_new = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(myblob.read()))
    df_final = process_data(df_base, df_new)
    df_final = df_final.to_csv(index=False)
    blobout.set(df_final.encode())
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "new-container/{name}",
      "connection": "my_storage"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "base",
      "path": "base-container/base.csv",
      "connection": "my_storage",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "blobout",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "base-container/base.csv",
      "connection": "my_storage"
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with function.json

Comment: updating it  ....

Comment: updated please give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, this was working fine. I believe that the there is no value that is getting returned from `process_data`. Make sure there is no null value that is getting returned from `process_data`. Below is a sample code that I used in `process_data` which gave me expected results.

```
def process_data(df_base,df_new):
    final_dataframe = pd.concat([df_base, df_new])
    return final_dataframe
```

**init.py**

```
import logging
import pandas as pd

import azure.functions as func
from io import BytesIO

def main(myblob: func.InputStream, base: func.InputStream, blobout: func.Out[bytes]):
    df_base = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(base.read()))
    df_new = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(myblob.read()))
    df_final = process_data(df_base, df_new)
    df_final = df_final.to_csv(index=False)
    blobout.set(df_final.encode())
    
def process_data(df_base,df_new):
    final_dataframe = pd.concat([df_base, df_new])
    return final_dataframe
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "new-container/{name}",
      "connection": "<STORAGE_CONNECTION>"
    },
    {
      "name": "base",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "base-container/base.csv",
      "connection": "<STORAGE_CONNECTION>",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "blobout",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "base-container/base.csv",
      "connection": "<STORAGE_CONNECTION>",
      "direction": "out"
  }
  ]
}
```

*RESULT*

[image]

Comment: yeah. My code was working fine. but the only problem was my patience. The blob write-up was taking ~3 minutes and I was thinking that the blob size is 0 bytes.